# Bootstrap website not displaying properly on large monitors

Tags: html

[image]

I'm preparing to launch a startup in a few weeks, and obviously one of the most important things before launching is to have a website. The website works fine on my laptop, and on mobile phones, however on my main PC (which has a 34" monitor), half of the screen is left empty.

[image]

As you can see, when I resize my window I get the site being displayed fully (in the first image, there's a lot of white space with the blue message us button on the bottom right).

The file is quite large but I'm wondering if anyone could have a look at it (the repo's at https://github.com/acord-robotics/acord-robotics.github.io) and the website's at http://acord.software.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the shortest possible reproducing example of the issue in the question, people are generally not going to search through your repo to find the problem. (Though as a starting point: it looks like either your background image isn't set to cover the component, or the body element isn't filling the whole page)

Comment: Hey, the index.html file is the file that's the home page. Thanks for the response, I'll take a look :)